# how to send intent in two different class at fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a variable that is sent through ntent, and sent to two different classes, how?
so my intent like this:

```
    case 0:
position = new LatLng (-8.447159, 112.651799);
args.putParcelable ("place_position", position);
a = new Intent (getActivity (), MapsMenu.class);
a.putExtra ("lat", args);
a.putExtra ("post", "cave");
a.putExtra ("location", "South Beach Goa China in Malang");
break;
```

Key 'post' sent to class A, while the key 'location' and 'lat' sent to class B, I use a fragment of actionsherlock, for variable successfully sent to class B, while for class A does not appear, the following source code:

```
public class A extends SherlockListFragment {
    ListView list;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ImageView imDetail;
    String pos;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in = getActivity().getIntent();
            pos = (String) in.getStringExtra("post");
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

and this is B class :

```
public class B extends SherlockMapFragment {
String title;
private GoogleMap map;
LatLng LAT = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    map = getMap();
    Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("lat");
    Intent in = getActivity().getIntent();
    title = (String) in.getStringExtra("location");
    LAT = bundle.getParcelable("place_position");

    LoadMaps(LAT, title);
    return root;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: fragments dont get intents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its fix now, My mistake was in calling variable in the next method, the intent has been successfully sent to two different classes using the above method.

Answer (score 1):

You put two items into the Intent called *"post"* and *"location"*. But you search for *"pos"* and *"lokasi"*. I think that's why the Class cannot find your Intent-Items.

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake to write it down here, I had to translate into English, actually 2 of the same key, but in class A remains undelivered, but in class B sent.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same string key to get the value from intent

```
a.putExtra ("post",...)

getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("post");
```